# android mapsforge overlay doesn't show in view

Tags: dictionary, overlay, android-mapview

I need a little help. I wrote an android app using "org.mapsforge.android.maps".
There I create a custom overlay wich I wanna show in the map. The map is shown but without my Overlay. I see that "mapView.getOverlays().add(myOverlay)" adds myOverlay to mapView but on the screen nothing happens.
Does someone has an idea why not?

Thanks a lot

Tom

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     try
     {
         res= this.getResources();
         context=this;
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
         setContentView(R.layout.openstreet);
         getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.main_title_back);



         // get the pointers to different system services
         this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         this.myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener(this);


         if(getIntent().hasExtra("comingfrom") == true)
             comingfrom = getIntent().getExtras().getString("comingfrom");
         if(getIntent().hasExtra("latitude") == true)
             mlatitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
         if(getIntent().hasExtra("longitude") == true)
             mlongitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("longitude");

         initMapView();

         Log.i(Properties.getProgramname(), "OpenStreetActivity->onCreate: Übergebene Koordinate Lat=" + mlatitude + " Lon=" + mlongitude);

         if (comingfrom.equals("ButtonArea"))
         {
             LoadData();
         }
         else
         {

         }

         if (this.locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
             initMyLocation(true);
            } else {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"GPS Provider not enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // create a GeoPoint with the latitude and longitude coordinates   
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(mlatitude, mlongitude);
        mapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
        mapController.setZoom(16);


     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.e(Properties.getProgramname(), "Fehler in OpenStreetActivity->onCreate: " +  ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         Toast.makeText(this,"UI problem " + ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
 }


 /**
 * Initialize the OSM 
 * 
 */
 private void initMapView()
 {
    settingsLayer = new TJHookerSettingsLayer(this);
    Cursor cur = settingsLayer.ladeSettings();
    String filename =cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(TJHookerSettingsTables.MAPFILE));
    cur.close();
    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    this.mapView.setClickable(true);
    this.mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.mapView.setFocusable(true);

     if (!this.mapView.getMapGenerator().requiresInternetConnection() ) {
         File file = new File(filename);
         if (file.exists())
             mapView.setMapFile(new File(filename));
         else
             Toast.makeText(this,"Problem: Mapfile not found. Please correct the path of your mapfile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     mapController = this.mapView.getController();
 }

 /**
 * Show the current location of my position
 * 
 */
 private void initMyLocation(boolean centerAtFirstFix) 
 {
     try
     {
         Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
         criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
         String bestProvider = this.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

         this.itemizedMyLocationOverlay = new ArrayItemizedOverlay(null);            
         this.overlayMyLocationItem = new OverlayItem();
         this.overlayMyLocationItem.setMarker(ItemizedOverlay.boundCenter(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_location)));
         this.itemizedMyLocationOverlay.addItem(this.overlayMyLocationItem);

         this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.itemizedMyLocationOverlay);

         this.myLocationListener.setCenterAtFirstFix(centerAtFirstFix);
         this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 0, this.myLocationListener);


     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Log.e(Properties.getProgramname(), "Fehler in OpenStreetActivity->initMyLocation: " +  ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         Toast.makeText(OpenStreetActivity.this, "!initMyLocation: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
     }
 }    


        // neuen Thread starten
        private void LoadData()
        {
            if(mlongitude > 0 && mlatitude  > 0)
            {
                SystemInformation sys = new SystemInformation();
                if(sys.isNetworkAvailable(this))
                {
                    // Neuen Thread startenn der die Kontakte laden soll. Activity wir schon angezeigt
                    prog = ProgressDialog.show(this, res.getString(R.string.gc40_progtitle), "", true, false);
                    prog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='white'>" + res.getString(R.string.gc40_progtext) + "</font>"));  

                    pdIsShow=true;
                    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
                    thread.start();   
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            GCApiRequests _apiRequests= new GCApiRequests();
            try {
                lc = _apiRequests.GetCacheByArea(Properties.getGCAccessToken(), mlongitude, mlatitude,"5000", GeocachingConstants.maxCachesPerPage);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Properties.getProgramname(), "KartenAnzeigenActivity->Fehler in run: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

            }

        }     

           // Wenn Thread alle Kontakte geladen hat, dann in ListView anzeigen
        private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (pdIsShow)
                    prog.dismiss();
                setOverlayCaches();
                }
        };          
        private void setOverlayCaches()
        {
            try {
                CacheType typ = new CacheType();
                lc.trimToSize();
                Log.i(Properties.getProgramname(), "OpenStreetActivity->setOverlayCache: Anzahlgefundener Caches=" +lc.size());
                /** So, jetzt gehen wir erstmal durch alle Logs von geocaching.com durch  */
                // create an ItemizedOverlay with the default marker
                CacheOpenStreetMapItemizedOverlay myOverlay= new CacheOpenStreetMapItemizedOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(typ.getCacheType(2)), context);
                for(Geocache cache: lc)
                {

                    // create a GeoPoint with the latitude and longitude coordinates
                    int lat = (int) (Double.parseDouble(cache.GetLatitude()) * 1e6);    
                    int lon = (int) (Double.parseDouble(cache.GetLongitude()) * 1e6);
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat,lon);

                    // create an OverlayItem with title and description
                    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, cache.GetCacheName(), cache.GetGCCode(),
                            getResources().getDrawable(typ.getCacheType(Integer.parseInt(cache.GetCacheType()))));
                    myOverlay.addOverlay(item);
                }   
                myOverlay.requestRedraw();
                // add the ArrayItemizedOverlay to the MapView
                //if (traditionellOverlay != null)
                Log.i(Properties.getProgramname(), "OpenStreetActivity->setOverlayCache: Anzahl Overlay items=" + myOverlay.size());
                Log.i(Properties.getProgramname(), "OpenStreetActivity->setOverlayCache: Anzahl MapView Overlays=" + mapView.getOverlays().size());
                mapView.getOverlays().add(myOverlay);
                Log.i(Properties.getProgramname(), "OpenStreetActivity->setOverlayCache: Anzahl MapView Overlays=" + mapView.getOverlays().size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Properties.getProgramname(), "KartenAnzeigenActivity->Fehler in setOverlayCaches: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        }


        /** Back-Button in Titlebar wurde gedrückt */
        public void PressTitleBackButton_Click(View view)
        {
            /** Durch ein finish() wird der Back-Button Effekt ausgelöst. */
            finish();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

You have to rewrite the code to:

```
int cachetyp = typ.getCacheType(Integer.parseInt(cache.GetCacheType()));
Drawable itemMarker = getResources().getDrawable(cachetyp);

// Without that the icons aren't displayed. So you NEED it
itemMarker.setBounds(0, 0, itemMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(), itemMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

The item need the bounds.....